# Can we use EJS tags with ChartsJS?

Tags: node.js, chart.js, ejs

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
    datasets: [{
    labels: <%- JSON.stringify(state_names); %>
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: <%- JSON.stringify(confirm_cases); %>,
    backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
    }]
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Above is my code to plot a chart using Charts.js. However, The labels array gives me a problem. The data field of charts is successfully incorporated. Can someone please help me out with this? "state_names" and "confirm_cases" are arrays being sent from the app.js file in the node project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your labels array is in the wrong space, it has to be in the `data` object on the same level as the `datasets` object is like this:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: < % -JSON.stringify(state_names); % >
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: < % -JSON.stringify(confirm_cases); % > ,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
}); 
</script>
```